# How to use SPWindowsService

Tags: sharepoint, windows-services, spwindowsservice

From what I understand from the sparse documentation on MSDN, the way to do long running jobs in SharePoint is to use a SPWindowsService. I would like an example on how to create a custom windows service to run in the context of a SharePoint farm.

Comment: How long is "long"? *X* number of hours, or days?

Comment: Hopefully just minutes, if you want to propose using OWSTimer this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SPWindowsService you should create a custom SharePoint Timer Job that executes periodically or once. There are quite a few examples out there on the web, but start with Andrew Connell's examples and go from there:

**MSDN Visual How To: Creating, Deploying, and Debugging Custom Timer Jobs in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0**
Learn how to harness the power of custom timer jobs in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc427068.aspx

Comment: I am aware of SharePoint Timer Jobs, but I do not wish to use them, as I have already specified in a reply to a comment to my question. I have good reasons why I wish to use a fully custom service.

Answer (score 0):

The following MSDN article should give enough information about how to integrate Windows Services with SharePoint and use the SPWindowsService class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569748.aspx